# Zend Framework: How do i secure zend url pattern?

Tags: security, zend-framework, url

I am using url rewrite controller to make custom urls. No i dont know how to secure them or if the user types some thing else then how do i show a page not found error.

Here is how i am making custom urls in my application index:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(                        
                    '([A-Z]*(([\/][A-Z0-9\-]*([\/][A-Z]*)?)?))',
                    array('controller'=>'Uriprocess','action'=>'index'),
                    array(1 => 'URI')
                );
    $router->addRoute('URIPROCESS',$route);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check [Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html#zend.controller.plugins.standard.errorhandler)

> Since the ErrorHandler plugin captures not only application errors,
>   but also errors in the controller chain arising from missing
>   controller classes and/or action methods, it can be used as a 404
>   handler. To do so, you will need to have your error controller check
>   the exception type.